# How to use "dag" json in aws_glue_job in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-glue, terraform-provider-aws

I am hoping to use Terraform to help me create some Glue jobs.

The Glue job examples I found in the [Terraform document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_job) are all using script in S3, for example:

```py
resource "aws_glue_job" "example" {
  name     = "example"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.example.arn

  command {
    script_location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket}/example.py"
  }
}
```

Besides creating a Glue job from script. There is another way.

I can export a "dag" json from the Glue job UI by clicking the "Download" button.

The "dag" json looks like

```
{
    "jobConfig": {
        "name": "write_parquet_to_delta_lake",
        // ...
    },
    "dag": {
        "node-1690143235825": {
            "name": "raw_parquet",
            // ...
        },
        "node-1690146104048": {
            "name": "sink_to_delta_lake",
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it is a direct mapping of the UI elements. And I can also create a Glue job by this "dag" json by clicking "Upload" button.

[image]

I am wondering for Terraform, is there a way to use this "dag" json instead of the script in S3?

Because when I create the Glue job in this way, I can still visualize it in the Glue job UI.

Comment: What is "dag json"? Any link to its documentation?

Comment: Hi @Marcin it is a nickname I give. I provided an example how this "dag" json actually looks after I downloading this json file from the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. I use the visual editor to create what I want, and then I copy the generated script and use it in Terraform.

The downside is as you mention that you can not continue in the editor based on the script. If I need some changes later I create what I need in the visual editor for a new job, and then take the relevant code and incorporate it into the existing script.

Comment: Thanks @Atle for confirming! Same approach, I created a template job in the UI, and then copy the script out to use Terraform. 